# highcharts heatmap Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

first of all sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

I found this generic error in StackOverflow with another libraries but couldn't solve my problem.

I have a RoR app with highcharts, I'm using chartbar and columnbar charts without problems, but now I tried to add heatmap and threw this error (my other charts blew up too when I included heatmap) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: chartBarContentsGenerator is not a function(anonymous function) @ report:262
report:328 Uncaught TypeError: chartBarContentsGenerator is not a function(anonymous function) @ report:328
application-babd633118c80bce803babb844831d35.js:30318 Uncaught Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
```

My applicacion.js looks like this :

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/modules/heatmap
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

I tried updating highcharts, including more files like exporting.js, highstock.js, changing the order of the lines but nothing worked.

This is my jsfiddle with this chart working

https://jsfiddle.net/llermaly/pay7pe9u/2/

*New INFO:

I added this 2 lines to my application.html.erb instead of using js assets but now only heatmap chart works

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
```

Any comment is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt notice about versions, I'm using an old version of highcharts (4.1.9) , then I included the newest version of heatmap (4.2.3) and had this error , then I updated all files to 4.2.3 but had conflicts with another js files.

Finally I downgraded both heatmap and highcharts to 4.1.9v and worked :)

I hope this help somebody

Comment: How you have downgraded the heatmap version, I couldn't find the way doing so. Please share the details, from where you have got the older version for heatmap. I also have the same issue, I am using old version for highcharts - 2.x.x